# Как запретить установку приложения на конкретные модели телефонов?

Tags: android, публикация-приложений

Как запретить установку приложения (разрабатываемого в Андроид Студио) на конкретные модели телефонов?

В частности на телефон Samsung GT-19300, т.к. на нем происходит сбой из-за не понятной ошибки))

Comment: запрещать можно непосредственно в Google Developer Console

Comment: костыльщики))))

Answer (score 0):

Разовью подсказку от пользователя **Style-7**, что и составит ответ на поставленный вопрос. Вдруг, кому-нибудь еще пригодится)

Чтобы перейти к спискам поддерживаемых и исключенных устройств:

Войдите в **Play Console**.

**Выберите приложение**.

В меню слева нажмите **Управление релизом > Каталог устройств**.

Просмотрите и примите условия использования.

Просмотрите вкладки Все, Поддерживаемые и Исключенные.

С помощью **Фильтра** и **Поиска** отфильтруйте на экран нужные устройства, которые нужно исключить.

Кликайте по каждой группе устройств и с помощью соответствующих кнопок исключайте **группу устройств** (кнопка вверху страницы) **или конкретную модель** (кнопка внизу страницы)

Чтобы скачать список устройств в формате CSV, справа на странице нажмите Скачать список устройств.

И т.д.

Подробнее
[Ссылка](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7353455?hl=ru)